# If x and y then construction

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, remote-debugging

In a web app written in VB.NET .NET 4.0, using VS 2012, there is this line:

```
    serverPort = CInt(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT"))
    serverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")

    If serverPort = nonsecurePort And serverName.Contains("MyWebSite.com") Then

     more code if both clauses are true

    end if
```

As it turns out, nonsecurePort = 8089 and in this case serverport is 80 so we think should means the the app will not execute the code in the if clause, as the serverport is not equal to the nonsecurePort.

BUT in fact, we watch the code go right into code and we do not understand why. This is an ASP.NET app. We published it to a DEV web server and are debugging it remotely.

Why could this happen?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the `if` line and add a watch for both your `serverPort` and `nonsecurePort` variables? What are their values? Maybe you expect them to be 80 and 8089 but it's not the case? Obviously not if the program goes inside the if block. Can you track why the values are the same?

Comment: We did put a breakpoint there and stepped through. The values are 80 and 8089.

Comment: Does changing `And` to `AndAlso` or separating logic by parentesses `If (serverPort = nonsecurePort) And serverName.Contains("MyWebSite.com")` makes a difference?

Comment: For some reason in the server setup,when we attempt to access the dev server url from another computer, we get that failure. When we remote into the dev server and run it ,it is OK. It seems that running the dev url from another computer, the app cannot resolve the servername. I'm still unsure how this interferred with the logic, however.